# How to use Hiera data from source repository?

Tags: puppet

I've got a masterless Puppet setup and I'd like to simply add information such as package names based on `$::osfamily` for portability. It seems Hiera is made for this sort of thing, but I can't figure out how to actually **use Hiera data inside a source repository from a Puppet manifest within the same source repository** without modifying *anything* in `/etc`. Basically every piece of documentation seems to assume that I'd want to modify `/etc/puppetlabs/code/hiera.yaml` or `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` by hand whenever I use a different repository. Or am I completely misunderstanding Hiera?

If necessary I'd be OK with adding a puppet.conf to the repository and referencing that every time I run `puppet apply`, but how would I go about referring to *the current directory* as the root for the [`hiera_config`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#hieraconfig)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use hiera data with masterless setup. Just specify --hiera_config with hiera confiuration which specify where to look for hiera data.

Example:

```
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ puppet apply -t --modulepath=./modules/ --hiera_config=./hiera.conf manifests/a.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for trololo.lan in environment production in 0.31 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1449108414'
Notice: test: bar
Notice: /Stage[main]/A/Notify[test: bar]/message: defined 'message' as 'test: bar'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.02 seconds
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ cat hiera.conf
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /tmp/puppet/data
:hierarchy: common
:logger: console
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ cat data/common.yaml
a::foo: bar
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ cat manifests/a.pp
class { "a":
}
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ cat modules/a/manifests/init.pp
class a (
  $foo = "default msg"
){
  notify { "test: $foo":
  }
}
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ rm data/common.yaml
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$ puppet apply -t --modulepath=./modules/ --hiera_config=./hiera.conf manifests/a.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for trololo.lan in environment production in 0.32 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1449108454'
Notice: test: default msg
Notice: /Stage[main]/A/Notify[test: default msg]/message: defined 'message' as 'test: default msg'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.02 seconds
nkts@trololo:/tmp/puppet$
```

Comment: Thank you! (I [figured it out](https://github.com/l0b0/root/commit/a472c556486df234b754723b526c655dc1b9ebb0)  the meantime :P)